# optimum way to get tweets before specific tweet using tweepy

Tags: python, twitter, tweepy

Suppose that a twitter user has sent a tweet which has a specific tweet `id`. What is the best way to get `n` tweets from same user exactly before that specific tweet `id` using `tweepy`?

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read the official Twitter documentation :
https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/tweets/search/api-reference/get-search-tweets.html

And use the parameter `q` with `from:@user` and `count=10` where 10 is your "n" and`max_id=id` where "id" is your tweet id.

And read the officiel tweepy documentation for the seach API.

We can fix bugs for you but won't code for you.

Comment: Thanks Jeff. This is exactly what I want. I don't mean code. I wasn't familliar enough with twitter api. Thanks anyway :)